# P vs NP Clarification

Tags: complexity-theory

A problem is solvable in polynomial by a deterministic turing machine, and no solution exists which benefits from parallelism.

Will it be P or P-Complete or NP or NP-Complete?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that we are talking about a decision problem, it is in $\mathsf{P}$ since it is solvable in polynomial **time** by a deterministic Turing machine.

Whether the problem is $\mathsf{P}$-complete depends on which type of reduction you are considering.

The problem is in $\mathsf{NP}$ since $\mathsf{P} \subseteq \mathsf{NP}$.
We don't know whether such a problem is $\mathsf{NP}$-Complete, in fact this is a major open question in computer science.

Answer (score 2):

A decision problem is in NP if you can find the answer (and prove it's correct) in polynomial time if the answer is YES, and you are given a suitable hint. It's in P if you can find the answer in polynomial time. Obviously any problem in P is in NP, because you can solve it in polynomial time, whether the answer is YES or NO, and you can just ignore any hint.

It's unlikely to be NP-complete. Actually, it is widely believed that problems in P are NEVER NP-complete or NP-hard. Finding a prove for that is very, very, very hard.